# Kmodes cluster size change quite on each run

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am using kmodes clustering in r. Each time I run the below code I get different clusters size even after setting up the seed

```
set.seed(11) 
c1 = kmodes(data, 3, iter.max = 1000, weighted = FALSE)
```

I am looking for the output that do not change even after runing the same code again.. I understand the kmodes uses the quiet same techniques as Kmeans for initial random points.. if we set seed then Kmeans give same cluster size output but not for Kmodes..

Thanks

Rahul

Answer (score -1):

Using this simple code we can investigate if the results given by `kmodes` can be reproduced using `set.seed`:

```
library(klaR)
set.seed(1)
x <- rbind(matrix(rbinom(250, 2, 0.25), ncol = 5),
           matrix(rbinom(250, 2, 0.75), ncol = 5))
colnames(x) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

nreps <- 10
mtx <- matrix(0, nrow(x), nreps)
for (k in 1:nreps) {
  set.seed(123)
  mtx[, k] <- kmodes(x, 3, iter.max = 1000, weighted = FALSE)$cluster
}
```

The output of `kmodes` do not change in the `nreps` runs

```
apply(mtx,2,function(x) all(x==mtx[,1]))

[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: "Proof by example" never was a good idea... don't do it. Maybe your data set is just too easy, so it will always find the same minimum? You may need a harder data set (and not a numerical data set?)...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Before posting this example I carefully checked the code inside the `kmodes` and did not find any reason for non reproducibility of results. The only element of randomness inside the algorithm seems to be the `sample` command: `modes <- unique(data)[sample(nrow(unique(data)))[1:k]`. This is why I posted this example.

Comment: Thanks this was a great help... Problem was in my R i guess. as after settin the seed I am gettin different output with different iterations but the same code in other system gettin same no. of output cluster.. no idea why...